# How can I check if other hosts are connected to a device's adb

Tags: android, adb

I'm hosting a pool of emulators on a server that exposes the devices on different IPs. They are used to run test suits from our CI and from the developers. Is there any way I can check if another host(dev or ci job) is already adb-connected to it so that I can make them use another device ?

I thought about some adb shell commands that look at network connections such as netstat but I couldn't find useful information.